# Why to have multiple duplicated method realizations used in Tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

In the online MSDN article ["How to: Wait on One or More Tasks to Complete"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), there is a piece of code:

```
// Try three different approaches to the problem. Take the first one
tasks2[0] = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => TrySolution1());
tasks2[1] = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => TrySolution2());
tasks2[2] = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => TrySolution3());
```

calling 3 different methods all of which do exactly the same having exactly the same body:

```
static double TrySolution1()
//static double TrySolution2()
//static double TrySolution3() 
{
   int i = rand.Next(1000000);
   // Simulate work by spinning
   Thread.SpinWait(i); 
   return DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
}
```

I cannot grasp what these multiple duplicated realizations illustrate?

What is the difference with usig one method

```
tasks2[0] = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => TrySolution1());
tasks2[1] = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => TrySolution1());
tasks2[2] = Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(() => TrySolution1());
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really would give you the same answer using one method.  The example is a "poor example" in that regard.  That being said, this is merely an example of how to approach the problem, not "real code" that you would use.

I suspect the thought behind it was to show you how to use multiple, separate methods (which would normally be implemented differently, of course) and determine which finished first.  I do believe the example would be more clear if a different implementation was used for each method, but the concepts being demonstrated would be identical.

Answer (score 1):

This is *sample* how something could be done. If you try to refactor pretty much any sample code it will always be something close to `return 0;`.

In this particular case it shows that if you would have several different things you can wait on competition of just one. Just ignore how functions are implemented - it is not what the sample demonstrates (if it confuses you - write your own distinct implementations of each function).

Comment: Isn't "different tasks doing the same thing (method)" still doing "several different things you can wait on competition of just one" in parallel?  The code just misleads and confuses the beginners like me